# How to disable "warning MSB8051: Support for targeting Windows XP is deprecated" in VS2017?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017

Since about one of the latest updates to Visual Studio 2017 I started getting the following warning during the build of my MFC project:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v141_xp\Toolset.targets(39,5):
>   warning MSB8051: Support for targeting Windows XP is deprecated and
>   will not be present in future releases of Visual Studio. Please see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2023588 for more information.

How do I disable this warning?

Here's the project configuration:

[image]

Comment: Search for "suppress msbuild warning".

Comment: @zett42: All I can find [is this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f37e8ba0-0c56-487e-8c0e-4ce76c3e12b8/turn-off-msbuild-warning-msb8051?forum=msbuild), but that answer is incomplete. I don't understand how he jumps from `"Common Properties"->"User Macros"`

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your .vcxproj file either into an existing PropertyGroup or one of its own.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <XPDeprecationWarning>false</XPDeprecationWarning>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or via command line

```
msbuild [project file] /p:XPDeprecationWarning=false
```

Another possibility is to go to your Property Manager window and "Add a new property sheet..." to your project. Right click on the new sheet and select "common Properties"->"User Macros"->"Add Macro" and use the name XPDeprecationWarning and a value of false. Sadly you can't just do this on your project as Visual Studio doesnt allow you to use the GUI to edit UserMacros on the root project file (I have always wondered why as the node is there in the file ).

These should all do exactly the same thing so if one is not working for you then I'm not sure why any of the others would be any more successful.

Comment: Thanks, I added it [as such](https://i.imgur.com/7fgAL5F.png) but it has no effect on that warning.

Comment: @c00000fd This could be too early in the file. Project file includes several common property sheets (*.props), which could possibly overwrite the setting. Try to put it after these includes.

Comment: @zett42: The first thing I did, I put it at the very end and got nothing either. Or, am I supposed to nest it inside the `ItemGroup` tag?

Comment: I just added to my project right at the top as you show in your png and it seems to work as expected. If you jump to the targets file in question you can see the line in question.
    <VCMessage Code="MSB8051" Type="Warning" Condition="'$(XPDeprecationWarning)' != 'false'" />
Which should only report if the XPDeprecationWarning property is not 'false' which yours should be. It needs to beincluded early byt including it in the PropertyGroup with the Label UserMacros should be fine. I am a little stumped as to why this may not be working for you...

Comment: **Enter this in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.user.props`** to get rid of it for all your projects.

Answer (score 1):

For those using separate property sheets (found in View --> Other Windows --> Property Manager) to combine properties from multiple projects into a single file, where mine is `AllCommon.props`, I was able to add replace a null `<PropertyGroup />` with

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <XPDeprecationWarning>false</XPDeprecationWarning>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

So the whole property file now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <XPDeprecationWarning>false</XPDeprecationWarning>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\MyCommonLibrary</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <CallingConvention>StdCall</CallingConvention>
      <TreatWarningAsError>true</TreatWarningAsError>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

This works, and I curiously didn't have to do anything with User Macros.  This file has to be edited by hand, as I have not found a way to do it with the GUI.